# Can I change the category name given to ILogger<T> instances?

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, obfuscation, ilogger

I have a custom `ILogger` implementation along with an `ILoggerProvider` and I've noticed that the `categoryName` parameter in `ILoggerProvider.CreateLogger` seems to be [`Type.FullName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.fullname?view=net-7.0):

> Gets the fully qualified name of the type, including its namespace but not its assembly.

However, my production code is obfuscated, and while not all consumers within the codebase are obfuscated, most are and their names become something insignificant (e.g. `╠`), but alas, this is the nature of obfuscation.

---

#### Answering @madreflection's comment

I took some time to create a setup to test out @madreflection's curiosity surrounding the `nameof` expression:

```cs
public class SampleAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SampleAttribute(string name) =>
        Name = name;
}
...
[Sample(nameof(InvoiceService))]
[Obfuscation(Exclude = false)]
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger) {
        var attribute = GetType().GetCustomAttribute<SampleAttribute>();
        logger.LogInformation($"inline: {nameof(TestClass)}");
        logger.LogInformation($"attribute: {attribute.Name}");
    }
}
```

The output shows that the `nameof` expression is not obfuscated:

> inline: TestClass
> attribute: TestClass

Now, I'm curious as to where they're going with it!

---

With this in mind, is there a documented way to change the category name to a constant value?

Comment: If you use `nameof`, does that get obfuscated, too? In particular, I'm curious about `[SomeAttribute(nameof(ThisClass))] class ThisClass`

Comment: Would you be interested in an *un*documented technique if it relies on only documented details?

Comment: @madreflection apologies for the delay in my response; I had an issue with my obfuscation setup I had to resolve before I could confirm or deny. I've updated my question to answer your first comment. In regards to your second question, an undocumented technique would be just fine!

Comment: And is that `attribute.Name` value sufficient for the category name, as opposed to a fully qualified type name?

Comment: @madreflection it absolutely is :) just need a way to still be able to tell what it is in an obfuscated state.

Comment: I'll write it up after work today.

Comment: @madreflection thank you so much for helping me explore this! I appreciate all of the help! Out of curiosity, are you looking into a custom `ILoggerFactory` implementation?

Comment: How did you know?  :)  Yes, it does involve that. In fact, if you're already thinking along those lines, you can probably guess where it's going to go.

Comment: @madreflection not quite yet lol though my gears are turning for sure. I'm likely missing a key point right now. I look forward to seeing your solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "simple" solution would be to inject `ILoggerFactory` and call `CreateLogger`.  The category name is a parameter so it can be provided directly.

However, injecting `ILogger<T>` is often the preferred pattern, and switching to injecting `ILoggerFactory` could be a non-trivial undertaking.  This solution helps avoid that.

---

There are 3 parts to this solution:

1. A custom attribute that can be used to mark a class or struct with a category name.
2. A custom `ILoggerFactory` implementation that replaces an obfuscated type name with the attribute value, if present.
3. An extension method for registering the custom `ILoggerFactory` implementation.

Thanks to @Taco タコス's testing, we know that the obfuscator in question isn't trying to find the type name in string literals and obfuscate it there.  That means that `nameof` can provide meaningful values for the category name in the attribute.

---

### The Attribute

First, we need an attribute.  It's nothing special, but here it is.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class LoggerCategoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public LoggerCategoryAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

This attribute can be applied to each class or struct that's used as the `T` in `ILogger<T>`.  It doesn't even have to be injected into that `T`'s constructor; it could be used anywhere.

### The Custom Logger Factory

Next, we'll create a custom `ILoggerFactory` implementation that wraps a real one.  The real logger factory could be the default `LoggerFactory` or it could be an implementation provided by another logging framework.

The `CreateLogger` method receives a `categoryName` parameter which *might* be a fully qualified type name, but it could be anything.  If `categoryName` is a type name and `Type.GetType` is able to find its `Type` instance, `CreateLogger` looks for the `LoggerCategory` attribute to get the name and assigns it to `categoryName` if it's not null/empty.  Otherwise, it leaves `categoryName` alone.

The other methods simply forward to the wrapped `ILoggerFactory` implementation.

```cs
public sealed class RecategorizingLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _originalLoggerFactory;

    public RecategorizingLoggerFactory(ILoggerFactory originalLoggerFactory)
    {
        _originalLoggerFactory = originalLoggerFactory;
    }

    public void AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider) => _originalLoggerFactory.AddProvider(provider);

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        Type? type = Type.GetType(categoryName);
        if (type is not null)
        {
            var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<LoggerCategoryAttribute>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute?.Name))
                categoryName = attribute.Name;
        }

        return _originalLoggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
    }

    public void Dispose() => _originalLoggerFactory.Dispose();
}
```

*Note: This class is `sealed` to avoid analysis messages about calling `GC.SuppressFinalize` in `Dispose`.*

### DI Registration

Finally, we need to register the custom logger factory for dependency injection.

If there's already a registration for `ILoggerFactory`, we can't use `Add` or `TryAdd` because the former would throw an exception and the latter would be a no-op.  Instead, we need to find the existing registration and replace it in the list.  Since `IServiceCollection` inherits `IList<ServiceDescriptor>`, it's easy to replace the service descriptor directly.

If there's no registration for `ILoggerFactory`, we add a new one, and create a new `LoggerFactory` to wrap, because our custom logger factory still needs to wrap *something* that can actually create loggers.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection InjectRecategorizingLoggerFactory(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

    // List<T> has FindIndex(), but IList<T> does not, so it's inline as a local function here.
    static int FindIndex(IList<ServiceDescriptor> list, Func<ServiceDescriptor, bool> predicate)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (predicate(list[i]))
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    int loggerFactoryIndex = FindIndex(services, sd => sd.ServiceType == typeof(ILoggerFactory));

    // These two variables will be assigned eventually.  Initializing them here prevents definite
    // assignment analysis from detecting that all branches of execution below have assigned
    // them, and with such large blocks, that can be a real concern, so they are intentionally
    // not initialized.
    Func<IServiceProvider, object> serviceFactory;
    ServiceLifetime lifetime;

    if (loggerFactoryIndex >= 0)
    {
        var oldServiceDescriptor = services[loggerFactoryIndex];
        lifetime = oldServiceDescriptor.Lifetime;

        // The service could be registered in one of three ways.  The first two are easy to support,
        // but the third can be fragile.  See the notes below the code for details.
        if (oldServiceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory is not null)
        {
            serviceFactory = oldServiceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory;
        }
        else if (oldServiceDescriptor.ImplementationInstance is ILoggerFactory oldLoggerFactory)
        {
            serviceFactory = sp => oldLoggerFactory;
        }
        else if (oldServiceDescriptor.ImplementationType is Type implementationType)
        {
            serviceFactory = sp =>
            {
                var loggerProviders = sp.GetServices<ILoggerProvider>();
                var filterOption = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<LoggerFilterOptions>>();
                var options = sp.GetService<IOptions<LoggerFactoryOptions>>();

                try
                {
                    // BANG: ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance is not annotated to accept null
                    //       elements in the 'arguments' parameter, but the constructor we want
                    //       to use takes a nullable IOptions<LoggerFactoryOptions>.  The method
                    //       signature is too restrictive, and passing null works where null is
                    //       allowed by the constructor.
                    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
                        sp,
                        implementationType,
                        new object[] { loggerProviders, filterOption, options! });
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new LoggerFactory(loggerProviders, filterOption, options);
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid service descriptor encountered for ILoggerFactory.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton;

        // No ILoggerFactory was registered.  Default to wrapping LoggerFactory.
        serviceFactory = sp => new LoggerFactory(
            sp.GetServices<ILoggerProvider>(),
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<LoggerFilterOptions>>(),
            sp.GetService<IOptions<LoggerFactoryOptions>>());
    }

    var newServiceDescriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(ILoggerFactory),
        sp => new RecategorizingLoggerFactory((ILoggerFactory)serviceFactory(sp)),
        lifetime);

    if (loggerFactoryIndex >= 0)
    {
        services[loggerFactoryIndex] = newServiceDescriptor;
    }
    else
    {
        services.Add(newServiceDescriptor);
    }

    return services;
}
```

Some points of note about the above code:

- Although the `loggerFactoryIndex >= 0` test could be done once with things moved around a bit, I did it twice because I only wanted one place where `newServiceDescriptor` is instantiated, since it's rather important and everything was intended to lead to that point.
- If an `ILoggerFactory` implementation other than the default `LoggerFactory` was already registered, and only if it was registered with `implementationType` rather than `implementationInstance` or `implementationFactory` (these are `AddSingleton` parameter names), `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` could fail.  This code contains a modest attempt not to hard-code `LoggerFactory`.  A lot more could be done to provide better support for wrapping other logger factories.  I'm leaving that as an exercise to the reader.
- I've used the "BANG:" comment to justify the use of the null-forgiving operator.  I've found that in code reviews, this has led to improvements in various ways once other eyes are drawn to it, often to the point of not needing to use the operator at all.  When it can't be rewritten away, it can help point out potential reasons for `NullReferenceException`s when the justification has ceased to be valid.
- There should be no reason to get an exception for an "invalid service descriptor" and `ServiceDescriptor` ensures proper construction, unless reflection were used to null out all the private fields.  It's primarily there for definite assignment analysis, as noted in one of the comments.

---

For completeness, and perhaps a bit of levity, here are some examples of how you might apply the attribute to a `HomeController` class.

```cs
// Confirmed, nameof works.
[LoggerCategory(nameof(HomeController))]

// But you don't have to use nameof if you don't wnat to.
[LoggerCategory("HomeController")]

// Who needs "Controller" anyway?  The *Name* of the controller is "Home", after all!
[LoggerCategory("Home")]

// You can include a hard-coded namespace so it looks like the original,
// unobfuscated type name.
[LoggerCategory($"MyApplication.Controllers.{nameof(HomeController)}")]

// A more robust version of the former.  As long as the depth of namespace
// doesn't change, this will capture renaming of *any* of the parts.
[LoggerCategory($"{nameof(MyApplication)}.{nameof(MyApplication.Controllers)}.{nameof(HomeController)}")]
```

Comment: I apologize for not accepting the answer yet, I haven't had a chance to run through all of it in practice yet. However, I wanted to take a moment to thank you for taking the time to write up such a thorough implementation and answer!

Comment: @Tacoタコス: Any questions you need me to answer?

Comment: No, I understand all of it, I just forgot to come back and accept the answer due to my current workload. I apologize for the delays, and thank you not only for your thoroughly helpful answer, but also the reminder that I need to accept it!